# Problem with my EventSubscriber in a Symfony 6 project

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

i am writing an application in Symfony 6, PHP 8. I need that my User are instantiated with a BU associated. I write an EventSubscriber which does that but it does not work. I want that when I create my User, the good BU goes in the array i create for it. The user are well created but the BU is empty.

I tried many other way to do what I want but I think this way is the best and the most secure, if it work obviously. I tried with a return or no return, I tried with "prePersist and preUpdate", i tried without an array in the condition.

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use App\Entity\UserLot;

class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber {
    
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security) {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::prePersist,
            // Events::preUpdate
        ];
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if ($entity instanceof UserLot) {
            return;
        }
        $this->setBU($entity);
        var_dump($entity);
    }
    private function setBU(UserLot $entity) {
        $BU = $entity->$this->getBuRequest1();
        $companyName = $entity->$this->getName();
        if( [] === $BU ){
            switch ($companyName) {
                case 'nom_de_la_company':
                    $listeBu1 = [
                        'BLA-BLA',
                        'BLA-BLA'];
                    $entity->setBuRequest1($listeBu1);
                    $listeBu2 = [
                        'BLA-BLA',
                        'BLA-BLA'];
                    $entity->setBuRequest2($listeBu2);
                case 'nom_de_la_company':
                    $listeBu1 = [
                        'BLA-BLA',
                        'BLA-BLA'];
                    $entity->setBuRequest1($listeBu2);
                        $listeBu2 = [
                        'BLA-BLA',
                        'BLA-BLA'];
                    $entity->setBuRequest2($listeBu2);
```

This is the first time I use StackOverflow. Excuse me if made something wrong.

Comment: I found that I put a "$this" where it does not need it in my definition.